# 1980s movie with chemicals placed in toothpaste make man explode

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have been searching for the name of this movie for so many years with no results. I can just remember bits and pieces. A man found out some secret information that he wasn't supposed to know, so another man broke into his home and placed a poisonous chemical in his toothpaste. When he brushed his teeth the chemical made him explode.

Additionally, I remember mutilated cows and an underground facility. Please help its been driving me crazy for years!

Answer (score 14):

[Endangered Species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endangered_Species_(1982_film)) has an underground facility, cattle mutilations  and Hoyt Axton exploding from a bio-weapon smeared on his toothbrush by a team of "Men in Black" working for a rogue government agency.

Edit: Found the moment of the [guy exploding](https://youtu.be/y1gQK60geH4?t=4739)

Comment: I was expecting more of a Scanners type explosion....

Comment: Yes, it is more like terminal flatulence. 